# Gmail's Apps script, assigning inbox label to thread

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

When I want to give a thread a user defined label, there is no problem. But problems start when I want to give just the system label "Inbox".

```
label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Inbox")

thread.addLabel(label)
```

I get this error:

> Invalid argument: label (line 2, file 'Code')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Gmail, "inbox" is a system label that, unlike user-created labels, is not accessible through the getLabels() method of the GmailThread class.

Note that if you log into your Gmail account and  type in "label: inbox" into the search bar, it will return the list of threads with the visual label "inbox" applied to them.

For security reasons, you can only interact with system labels like "inbox" or "spam" using the methods that Google wrapped around them. In the following example, the result is the same as applying the "inbox" label to a thread:

```
      var thread = GmailApp.getThreadById("yourId");

      if(!thread.isInInbox()) {

            thread.moveToInbox(); //apply the inbox label

                   }
```

You can also filter inbox messages by using the search() method of the GmailApp class:

```
    var threads = GmailApp.search("label: inbox from: contact@example.com");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it sure helped me!

Answer (score 0):

`GmailLabel` is 'a user-created label' [by definition](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label), so I guess you cannot add a system label like 'inbox'. We cannot apply inbox label even in Gmail web UI either.

Comment: Are you certain about the web UI? Because I can move a mail by clicking to "Move to inbox". Or is the MoveToInbox() method the only way to give a message the Inbox label?

Comment: Moving to inbox is not applying a label. There's no label like 'inbox'.